# Find the square root of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be the matrix
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
41 & 12\\
12 & 34
\end{array}\right).$$

I want to decompose it into the form of $B^2$.

I tried diagonalization , but can not move one step further.

Any thought on this? Thanks a lot!

ONE STEP FURTHER:

How to find a upper triangular $U$ such that $A = U^T U$?

Comment: The matrix is symmetric, so it is certainly diagonalizable. Trace and determinant are both positive, so both eigenvalues are positive. So if you can diagonalize, the diagonal form will have a square root, $QAQ^{-1} = D = P^2$, where $Q$ is the change-of-basis matrix. That means that $A = Q^{-1}P^2Q = (Q^{-1}PQ)^2$, so you can let $B=Q^{-1}PQ$. So your idea works; where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin I did not figure out how to use the diagonalized form. Your answer is brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#How_to_diagonalize_a_matrix

Comment: Re: edit: *Cholesky decomposition* can be done with an approach similar to Gerry's: write out the expression for the product of a lower triangular matrix with its transpose, equate to your original matrix, and solve the resulting set of equations...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is an expansion of Arturo's comment.

The matrix has eigenvalues $50,25$, and eigenvectors $(4,3),(-3,4)$, so it eigendecomposes to $$A=\begin{pmatrix}4 & -3 \\ 3 & 4\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}50 & 0 \\ 0 & 25\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}4 & -3 \\ 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}^{-1}.$$

This is of the form $A=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$. If this is $B^2$, then there will be a $B$ of the form $Q\Lambda^{1/2} Q^{-1}$ (square this to check this is formally true). A square root of a diagonal matrix is just the square roots of the diagonal entries, so we have

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}4 & -3 \\ 3 & 4\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{50} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{25}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}4 & -3 \\ 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$

$$=\frac{1}{5}\begin{pmatrix}9+16\sqrt{2} & -12+12\sqrt{2} \\ -12+12\sqrt{2} & 16+9\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Here we used $\sqrt{50}=5\sqrt{2},\sqrt{25}=5$, and a quick formula for the inverse of a $2\times 2$ matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}.$$

Keep in mind that matrix square roots are not unique (even up to sign), but this particular method is guaranteed to produce one example of a real matrix square root whenever $A$ has all positive eigenvalues.

---

Finding an upper triangular $U$ such that $A=U^TU$ is even more straightforward:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} a&0 \\ b&c \end{pmatrix} \cdot  \begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ 0&c \end{pmatrix} $$

This is $a^2=41$ hence $a=\sqrt{41}$, $ab=12$ hence $b=\frac{12}{41}\sqrt{41}$, and $b^2+c^2=34$ hence $c=25\sqrt{\frac{2}{41}}$.

In other words,

$$U=\sqrt{41}\begin{pmatrix}1&\frac{12}{41}\\0&\frac{25}{41}\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}. $$

Comment: Could you provide a source for this please? That would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Pubbie What do you want a source for? This answer seems self-contained to me.

Comment: Writing a paper concerning this.

Comment: @Pubbie In any paper I'd write I wouldn't bother with a citation for a fact like this.

Comment: The reviewer specifically requested it.

Comment: @Pubbie Haha, wow. Well, I don't really know a good reference to give you, sorry.

Comment: I found it in the book $\textit{Functions of Matrices}:$ Theory and Computation.

Comment: why the eigenvectors of a matrix and its square root is same?

Comment: @sawankt I never said they were, though I gave a method to compute *a* square root which is symmetric with the same eigenvectors. In general, the eigenvectors of $B$ are also eigenvectors of $B^2$, so if $B$ is symmetric then so is $B^2$ and they have the same sets of eigenvectors. *Conversely*, then, any *symmetric* square root of a symmetric matrix $A$ must have the same set of eigenvectors as $A$.

Answer (score 24):

For the first part of your question, here is a solution that only works for 2-by-2 matrices, but it has the merit that ***no eigenvalue is needed***.

Recall that in the two-dimensional case, there is a magic equation that is useful in many situations. It is $X^2-({\rm tr}X)X+(\det X)I=0$, which arises from the characteristic polynomial of a $2\times2$ matrix $X$. Now, if $X^2=A$, we have $\det X=\pm\sqrt{\det A}=r$ (say). We take the positive value for $r$. Hence
$$
(\ast):\quad ({\rm tr}X)X=X^2+rI=A+rI
$$
and $({\rm tr}X)^2 = {\rm tr}\left(({\rm tr}X)X\right) = {\rm tr}(A+rI) = {\rm tr}A + 2r$. Thus, from $(\ast)$ we obtain
$$
X = \frac{1}{\sqrt{{\rm tr}A + 2r}}(A+rI)\quad {\rm where}\quad r=\sqrt{\det A}.
$$
This method works for all 2-by-2 matrices $A$ when $\det A\ge0$ and ${\rm tr}A + 2\sqrt{\det A}>0$. In particular, it works for positive definite $A$.

For the second part of your question, as the others have pointed out, the decomposition you ask for is a [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Comment: Dear @user1551: It seems to me your condition ${\rm tr}A + 2\sqrt{\det A}>0$ just means that the eigenvalues are positive. Is this correct? I also think that your formula is exactly the same as Didier's. [Mine is slightly different (but equivalent) because I haven't been smart enough to cover the two cases by a single formula.]

Comment: Yes, the eigenvalues have to be non-negative and at least one of them must be positive, and our formulae are equivalent. I think you are being modest when you said you were not smart enough. Since mathematicians in this forum tend to analyze problems (and generalize the results) from higher perspectives, it is not surprising that you guys do not take a low road as I did.

Comment: I might be modest, ... but less than you! I mention you and Didier in an edit to my answer. I think my road is lower than yours: I try to express things in the high school language of secant and tangent lines.

Comment: No, my road is certainly lower than yours, because my method cannot be generalized to higher dimensions.

Comment: Your method looks very original to me. It's very natural to use Cayley-Hamilton, but I guess most people would have used it for $A$, not for $X$. That is, put $X:=xA+yI$, write $X^2=A$, use CH in the form $A^2=tA-dI$ (with $t=$ trace, $d=$ det) to get rid of the $A^2$ term. You get 2 equations for $x$ and $y$. *This* can be generalized.

Comment: Hi! I've just added an Edit 4 to my answer. (I put it *before* Edit 1.) It's in some way a continuation of our conversation.

Answer (score 7):

Still another explicit formula: for every nonnegative real number $\alpha$,
$$
A^\alpha=\frac{(u^\alpha-v^\alpha)A+(uv^\alpha-vu^\alpha)I}{u-v}
$$
where $u$ and $v$ are the two roots of the polynomial $\chi_A(x)=\det(xI-A)$. When $\alpha=1/2$, this yields
$$
\sqrt{A}=\frac{A+\sqrt{uv}I}{\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v}}
$$
Note that the coefficients of this formula can be computed directly from the matrix $A$ since $t=\sqrt{uv}$ is simply $t=\sqrt{\det A}$ and $s=\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v}$ is such that $s^2=u+v+2t$ hence 
$$
s=\sqrt{\text{tr}(A)+2\sqrt{\det(A)}}
$$
and, finally,

> $$
> \sqrt{A}=\frac{A+\sqrt{\det A}I}{\sqrt{\text{tr}(A)+2\sqrt{\det(A)}}}
> $$

In the present case, one can also compute $$\chi_A(x)=(x-41)(x-34)-12^2=(x-25)(x-50)$$ and use the values $\sqrt{u}=5\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt{v}=5$.

Comment: The formulae of yours, mine and @Pierre-Yves Gaillard are actually equivalent, but how they are expressed and derived are different.

Comment: @user1551, yes.

Comment: @didier Does this identity have a name or can you provide a reference?

Answer (score 6):

Let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be the eigenvalues of your $2$ by $2$ real matrix $A$. (We may have $\lambda=\mu$.) Assume that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are positive.

If $\lambda\not=\mu$, write the equation of the **secant line** to the curve $y=\sqrt x$ through the points $(\lambda,\sqrt\lambda)$ and $(\mu,\sqrt\mu)$: 
$$y=\sqrt\lambda\ \ \frac{x-\mu}{\lambda-\mu}+\sqrt\mu\ \ \frac{x-\lambda}{\mu-\lambda}\quad.$$ 
The matrix you want is 
$$\sqrt\lambda\ \ \frac{A-\mu I}{\lambda-\mu}+\sqrt\mu\ \ \frac{A-\lambda I}{\mu-\lambda}\quad,$$ 
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

If $\lambda=\mu$, write the equation of the **tangent line** to the curve $y=\sqrt x$ through the point $(\lambda,\sqrt\lambda)$: 
$$y=\sqrt\lambda+\frac{x-\lambda}{2\sqrt\lambda}\quad.$$ 
The matrix you want is 
$$\sqrt\lambda\ I+\frac{A-\lambda I}{2\sqrt\lambda}\quad.$$

Do you see why?

Do you see how to generalize this to $n$ by $n$ matrices?

**EDIT 4.** This is to just explain why this secant/tangent stuff comes into the picture. Assume to simplify that the eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$ of your two by two real matrix $A$ are real and distinct. Let $f\in\mathbb R[X]$ be a polynomial, and $s$ the unique polynomial of degree $\le1$ which agrees with $f$ at $\lambda$ and $\mu$. [Graphically, this is a secant line.] Then the characteristic polynomial $$\chi=(X-\lambda)(X-\mu)$$ will divide $f-s$. As $\chi(A)=0$ by the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, we have $f(A)=s(A)$. But the expression $s(A)$ makes sense whenever $f$ is a (real-valued) function defined at $\lambda$ and $\mu$. Moreover, the map $f\mapsto f(A)$ is compatible with addition and multiplication.

**EDIT 1.** As noticed by @Did and @user1551, there is a cute formula for the "generalized secant line" to the curve $y=\sqrt x$, by which I mean: the secant line if the points are distinct, the tangent line if they coincide. Supposing $\lambda\not=\mu$, the equation of the secant line is 
$$y=\frac{\sqrt\lambda-\sqrt\mu}{\lambda-\mu}\ \ x+
\frac{\mu\sqrt\lambda-\lambda\sqrt\mu}{\lambda-\mu}=
\frac{x+\sqrt{\lambda\mu}}{\sqrt\lambda+\sqrt\mu}\quad,$$ 
and the miracle is that the last expression makes sense even if $\lambda=\mu$.

**EDIT 2.** Note that there are other solutions when $\lambda\not=\mu$. Putting 
$$E:=\frac{A-\lambda I}{\mu-\lambda}\quad,\quad 
F:=\frac{A-\mu I}{\lambda-\mu}\quad,$$ 
we get $$E^2=E,\ F^2=F,\ EF=FE=0,\ I=E+F,\ A=\mu E+\lambda F,$$ 
and thus $$(\pm\sqrt\mu\ E\pm\sqrt\lambda\ F)^2=A$$ 
for the four choices of signs. [The plus plus choice corresponds to the previous formula.]

**EDIT 3.** Here is a generalization.

Let $T$ be an $n$ by $n$ complex matrix, and 
$$p(X)=(X-\lambda_1)^{m(1)}\cdots(X-\lambda_k)^{m(k)}$$ 
its minimal polynomial (the $\lambda_i$ being distinct and the $m(i)$ positive). Let $A$ be the algebra of those functions $f(z)$ which are holomorphic in a neighborhood of the spectrum $\{ \lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k \}$ of $T$.

There is a unique $\mathbb C[X]$-algebra morphism from $A$ to $\mathbb C[T]=\mathbb C[X]/(p(X))$. Denote this morphism by $f(z)\mapsto f(T)$. If $f(z)$ is in $A$, then the unique representative of $f(T)$ in $\mathbb C[X]$ of degree less than $\deg p(X)$ is 
$$\sum_{i=1}^k\ \ \underset{X=\lambda_i}\heartsuit\left(
\Big(\ \underset{z=\lambda_i}\heartsuit f(z) \Big)\ \ 
\frac{(X-\lambda_i)^{m(i)}}{p(X)}\ \right)\ 
\frac{p(X)}{(X-\lambda_i)^{m(i)}}$$

with 
$$\underset{u=\lambda_i}\heartsuit\varphi(u):=\sum_{j=0}^{m(i)-1}\frac{\varphi^{(j)}(\lambda_i)}{j!}\ (X-\lambda_i)^j.$$

Moreover, the $\lambda_i$-generalized eigenspace of $T$ is contained in the $f(\lambda_i)$-generalized eigenspace of $f(T)$.

All this follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem, which says 
$$\frac{\mathbb C[X]}{(p(X))}=\prod_{i=1}^k\ \ 
\frac{\mathbb C[X]}{(X-\lambda_i)^{m(i)}}\quad,$$ 
and from the Taylor Formula.

[There is an Edit 4 above.]

Answer (score 4):

Write $$\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}^2=\pmatrix{41&12\cr12&34\cr}$$ multiply out the left side, set corresponding entries equal to get four equations in the four unknowns $a,b,c,d$, then see if you can work your way through the algebra to a solution.

Comment: This method gets ugly in a hurry.  Once needs to solve $a^2 + b^2 = 41$, $b(a+d) = 12$, and $b^2 + d^2 = 34$ simultaneously.  As far as I can tell, there seems to be no clean algebraic solution.

Comment: I can work it out on a single sheet of paper (but I have very small handwriting...).

Comment: I won't ask for all the details, but what is your general process?

Comment: Subtract third equation from first to get a difference of two squares, and express $a+d$ and $a-d$ in terms of $b$ using the expression for $a+d$ you get from the second equation. This gives you $a$ in terms of $b$ and you can substitute in the first equation to get an equation you can solve for b.

It is much easier if you are allowed to guess that the answer can be expressed in integers.

Comment: Forget that last sentence

Comment: @DJC, $a^2-d^2=7$, $b/(a-d)=12/7$, $12a=7b+12d$, $b(7b+24d)=144$, $24^2b^4+(24bd)^2=(34)(24)^2b^2$, $24^2b^4+(144-7b^2)^2=(34)(24)^2b^2$ gives a biquadratic for $b$.

Comment: why the eigenvectors and its square root are same?

Answer (score 3):

The second is even simpler than the first question. All you need to to look at the assumed solution, setting unknowns:
$ \qquad \qquad \small A = U^t \cdot U = \begin{pmatrix} a&0 \\ b&c \end{pmatrix} \cdot  \begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ 0&c \end{pmatrix} \qquad  $ and $ \small a \cdot a = 41$. Then you can proceed; in Pari/GP it needs something like 5 lines of code...

Answer (score -3):

As traditional known the square root of any number would have two result, its cube root would have three results and so on
The matrix $$A^2 = $$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
41 & 12\\
12 & 34
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Has solutions as 
Matrix $$A =$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
6.3254834 & 0.9941125\\
0.9941125 & 5.7455844
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And
Also
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2.7254834 & 5.7941125\\
5.7941125 & -0.6544156
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This is a clear solution to the question, if you really checked well you'll see it.
I don't know why anyone here can block someone's comment, claiming it to be wrong