# Matrix equation $X^2 + E = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all real-valued $n\times n$ matrices $X$ such that 
$$
X^2 + E = 0,
$$

here  $E$ --- identity matrix, $n$ --- odd.

Comment: This question bears remarkable similarity to this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791333/find-all-3-times-3-matrices-x-such-that-x2e-0

Comment: $\det (-E) = 1$ of $n$ is even.  So his proof only applies to the case $n$ odd, as it should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X^2=-E$ and let $D$ be the determinant of $X$. Now, justify the following: $D^2=-1$. What do you conclude?

Comment: Oh! It means that X could not be real-valued. So, there are no such matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X^2+E=0$ you have that the if $f(x)=x^2+1$ then $f(X)=0$. Hence the minimal polynomial of $X$ divides $f(x)$ and so $m_X(x)=x^2+1$.

This means that the eigenvalues of $X$ are complex. But the characteristic polynomial of $X$ is of degree $n=odd$ so it has a real root. Contradiction. So there are no real matrices satisfying the given equation.