# Solve $X^2=A$, where X is a 2 by 2 matrix and A is a known matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

A = $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$
. I wrote X = $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$. So $X^2$=$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a^2+bc & ab+bd \\
        ac+bc & bc+d^2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ = $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

Unfortunatelly I don't know how to continue from here and maybe someone can help be find the matrix X

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59384/find-the-square-root-of-a-matrix

Comment: You can use this formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix#One_formula or other methods here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

From top-right and bottom-left elements we get:
$$(a+b)d = (a+b)c = -1 \Rightarrow c=-d$$

The top-left and bottom-right elements give us:
$$a^2 + bc = bc + d^2 = 1 \Rightarrow a^2 = d^2 \Rightarrow a = \pm d$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

You get:

$a^2 +bc$ = 1

$ac + bc$ = -1

$ab + bd$ = 1

$bc + d^2$ = 1

Hence use substitution to find a, b, c and d.