# What does "$\Sigma^{\frac12}$" mean in the context of variational auto encoders?

Tags: variance

I am studying about Variational Auto Encoders. I found the following equation.

> $$\mu +\Sigma^\frac12\odot\epsilon$$

I can imagine that $\Sigma$ is related to variance. What does the  $\Sigma^{1/2}$ mean? And how is the notation called? I can not find any good articles related to this.

Comment: $\Sigma$ is variance, and $\Sigma^{\frac12}$ is standard deviation?

Comment: One thing which would help is *where* you read that. Presumably, they define notation somewhere before. (Is $\epsilon$ an error or pertubation *vector*?)

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix (as it should if it's a covariance matrix), then presumably $\Sigma^{1/2}$ is its (well-defined) [matrix square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix).

Comment: The original source is in Japanese. But I found it refers a wikipedia article. I'm reading it now. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Geometric_interpretation

Comment: In normal distribution, I found two cases of definition $\mathcal{N}(\mu(x), \sigma(x))$
 and $\mathcal{N}(\mu(x), \Sigma(x))$. Do both "sigma" mean standard deviation? Does the latter want to focus the sigma is a matrix?

Comment: I am going to be blunt here: if you are not clear on what a covariance matrix (cf. my previous comment) is and a bit hazy on your linear algebra (so that you are not clear on what a positive semi-definite matrix and its square root are), maybe you should work on that before wanting to study neural nets and autoencoders.

Answer (score 2):

This literature is honestly not very well-notated in general. Let me try to clarify.

Usually a 1D normally distributed random variable $\widetilde{z}$ (dependent on some other variable $x$) is written like: $$ \widetilde{z}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu(x),\sigma(x)^2) $$
where $\mu(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ is the mean and $\sigma(x)^2\in\mathbb{R}$ is the variance. An *equivalent* value can be sampled via $ \widetilde{z} = \mu(x) + \varepsilon\sqrt{\sigma(x)} $ where $\varepsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Notice the square root is used to get the standard deviation.

Separately, a multivariate, normally distributed random variable is often written as:
$$ z\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu(x),\Sigma(x)) $$
where $z,\mu(x)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Sigma(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Note that $\Sigma(x)$ must be positive definite and symmetric in order to be a proper covariance matrix. In this case, we can sample a value via $z = \mu(x) + \sqrt{\Sigma(x)}\,\xi$, where $\xi\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I)$, $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Here, $\sqrt{\Sigma(x)}=\Sigma^{1/2}(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the *matrix square root*, i.e. $\Sigma^{1/2}(x)\Sigma^{1/2}(x)=\Sigma(x)$. Note that one *cannot* in general compute this by taking the square root of the elements of the matrix (though one can for *diagonal* matrices)! This can be non-trivial (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347952/how-to-find-a-matrix-square-root-with-all-real-entries-if-it-exists?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59384/find-the-square-root-of-a-matrix)).

However, for VAEs and the reparameterization trick, in *most* cases the covariance matrix is *defined to be diagonal*. This tells us two things: (1) the matrix-vector product $\sqrt{\Sigma}\xi$ becomes a Hadamard product, i.e. in this case $ \sqrt{\Sigma}\odot\xi= \sqrt{\Sigma}\xi$, and (2) the matrix root becomes an element-wise root, i.e.
$\Sigma = \text{diag}(\Sigma_1,\ldots,\Sigma_n)\;\implies\;\Sigma^{1/2}=\text{diag}(\Sigma^{1/2}_1,\ldots,\Sigma^{1/2}_n)$. Thus, sampling a value in a VAE with diagonal covariance becomes:
$$ z = \mu(x) + \sqrt{\Sigma(x)}\,\xi = \mu(x) + \Sigma^{1/2}(x)\odot\xi $$
where you don't have to worry about matrix roots, because you can take the elementwise root! :)