# Induction proof with matrix multiplication

Tags: proof-writing

I am working on the following exercise from Prof. Richard Earl (Oxford).

[image]

I completed the first part, which was quite straightforward. However, I don't know how to move to the second one.

[image]

I believe the second portion of the exercise requires the reader to use the first portion somehow, however, I do not know in what way.

Any guidance is highly appreciated

Comment: What happens if you put $n=\frac12$ in the formula for $A^n$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the square root of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59384/find-the-square-root-of-a-matrix)

Comment: @azif00 Cute...